# What's an opposite of "endless" that's like "startless"?

Tags: single-word-requests

To describe an event with a beginning but no end, meaning that it goes forever into the future, one could say it is "endless".

What word would describe an event with no beginning but an end, meaning that it goes forever into the past? 'Startless' doesn't seem to be used for this (or much at all).

In a sentence:

> They were so used to the custom that they considered its existence [to not have a beginning].

Comment: There are cycles or processes that don’t have a specific start point...

Answer (score 0):

Would "**sourceless**" or "**beginningless**" work for your question? I find them as words that seems to have few, if any, synonyms.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sourceless

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beginningless

Answer (score 0):

> canceled

A canceled meeting has an abrupt end (the moment it is canceled), but no beginning.

There are holes in my argument, but then again, the question is what to call something that ends, but never begins.